# How could I create a postgresql extension in django test setup

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using `django 1.11` and `PostgreSQL 9.6`. When I want to test an app, I find that the django test will create and use a test database.This test database doesn't have an extension that need to be created first.

So how to create an extension after create the test database and before create the test data？

Comment: What do you mean by "This test database doesn't have an extension that need to be created first."? Could you explain more precisely what you did, and what was the actual result and what was the goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you should do is apply your extensions to the `template1` database which is used for creating the new database for tests. As it is stated in [this article](https://blog.dbi-services.com/what-the-hell-are-these-template0-and-template1-databases-in-postgresql/) explaining the `template0` and `template1` databases:

> Whatever you put into template1 will be available in a new database if
>   you use the following syntax: “create database [DB_NAME];” This can
>   simplify your deployments a lot if you rely on pre-installed objects
>   for e.g. monitoring or development.

Simply run:

```
psql -d template1 -c 'command to create your extension here;'
```